# Run time error '1004' No cells were found error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My code below shows how to filter certain range with depends on the value of a column. Whenever I tried the 2nd case and 3rd case I am getting the runtime error.

Hi Jeeped, kindly review below edited code:

```
Private Sub cmdATSend_Click()
'**************************************************************
'Copy Data
'**************************************************************

Dim myProject As String, sCriteria As String

myProject = InputBox("On what sheet do you wish to transfer these data?", "Daily Alarms Tracker", "ONO, INFINITY, or NET Brazil?")

With Sheets("Daily Alarms Tracker")

    sCriteria = vbNullString
    Select Case myProject

        Case "INFINITY", "infinity", "Infinity", "inf", "Inf"
            sCriteria = "INFINITY"
        Case "ONO", "Ono", "ono"
            sCriteria = "ONO"
        Case "NET Brazil", "NET", "net brazil", "net", "Net Brazil", "NET BRAZIL"
            sCriteria = "NET Brazil"
    End Select

    If CBool(Len(sCriteria)) Then
        With .Range("C7:K18")
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sCriteria
            '.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Select
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count))) Then
                .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Copy
            Else
                Debug.Print "nothing matches"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End With

'*******************************************************************
'Paste Data
'*******************************************************************

   Dim atwb As Workbook

   Set atwb = Workbooks.Open("https://ts.company.com/sites/folder1/folder2/01%20Project%20Documentations/Daily%20Alarms%20Tracker/Daily_Alarms_Tracker.xlsx")
   Set atwb = ActiveWorkbook

   Select Case sCriteria

        Case "INFINITY"
            Dim iRow As Long

                With Sheets("INFINITY")
                    eRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B:B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(iRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End With

        Case "ONO"
            Dim oRow As Long

                With Sheets("ONO")
                    eRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B:B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(oRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End With

        Case "NET"
            Dim nRow As Long

                With Sheets("NET")
                    eRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B:B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(nRow, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                End With

    End Select

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a variable to store the criteria from the `Select Case` and only copied values to the clipboard when there are filtered records. A `.Copy` on filtered rows will only copy the visible ones.

```
Private Sub cmdATSend_Click()
    Dim myProject As String, sCriteria As String, sTargetWS As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, atWB As Workbook

    myProject = InputBox("On what sheet do you wish to transfer these data?", "Daily Alarms Tracker", "ONO, INFINITY, or NET Brazil?")

    'open the target wb now for direct use later
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set atWB = Workbooks.Open("https://ts.company.com/sites/folder1/folder2/01%20Project%20Documentations/Daily%20Alarms%20Tracker/Daily_Alarms_Tracker.xlsx")

    With wb.Sheets("Daily Alarms Tracker")

        sCriteria = vbNullString: sTargetWS = vbNullString
        Select Case myProject

            Case "INFINITY", "infinity", "Infinity", "inf", "Inf"
                sCriteria = "INFINITY"
                sTargetWS = "INFINITY"
            Case "ONO", "Ono", "ono"
                sCriteria = "ONO"
                sTargetWS = "ONO"
            Case "NET Brazil", "NET", "net brazil", "net", "Net Brazil", "NET BRAZIL"
                sCriteria = "NET Brazil"
                sTargetWS = "NET"
        End Select

        If CBool(Len(sCriteria)) Then
            With .Range("C7:k18")
                .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sCriteria
                'with .offset(1,0).resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count))) Then
                    .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Copy _
                      Destination:=atWB.Sheets(sTargetWS).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Else
                    Debug.Print "nothing matches"
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With

    'you could close the Daily_Alarms_Tracker workbook here
    'atWB.Close savechanges:=True

    Set atWB = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

 End Sub
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the values but at the end of this private sub there may be rows copied to the clipboard. Some error control in case there are no records may be appropriate. It would seem that *sCriteria* holds the name of the destination worksheet.

Comment: May I ask on how will I paste the copied cells?

Comment: Actually, I prefer direct data transfer from cell to cell or a `.Copy Destination:=...` style transfer. To paste you would have to go to the active sheet and that is to be avoided. If you can edit your original question to include the destination worksheet and cell (or description of location like first empty cell in column A) then I will have something to work with. Without knowing the destination, it is pretty hard to pick the best method.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. I have already edited my original question. Kindly check. Thank you! :)

Comment: @xtina1231 - The paste operation seemed to be pretty close to a standard paste that carries the values and formatting with it so I opted for the `.Copy Destination:=...` method and used a second string var to set the name of the target worksheet. The target workbook had to opened prior to using it but it had to be opened at some time anyway.

Comment: The workbook has opened, but the copied data has not been pasted to the selected sheet.

Comment: @xtina1231 - Perhaps it was opened as read only due to it coming from the Internet. Check all of your security settings. FWIW, I just ran a full test on two workbooks with your Internet one being a workbook in my local documents folder and the code ran as expected.

Comment: You can try to use your old *Paste Data* section. The name of the target worksheet is in *sTargetWS*.